can't implement interface member 'IStoreListener.OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason, string)'
I have a script that I bought online, but it contains errors that I don't know how to solve
Assets\Scripts\Purchaser.cs(14,41): error CS0535: 'Purchaser' does not implement interface member 'IStoreListener.OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason, string)'
this is built in unity version 2021.3.38f1
I would like to know the solution because I am a practitioner and still learning

The error says that the script Purchaser inherites the interface 'IStoreListener' which has a member/method 'OnInitializeFailed' which was not implemented in your script Purchaser.cs. You can implement it on your own, but I recommend to check the documentation if the asset has any, and see what it does.

Click on 'IStoreListener' in script where it is being implemented. Press
"Ctrl + ." (if you're using VS) it will show you suggestion to implement the missing member. Just press enter.
